# How to show feeds in the same page after applying filters in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

i am creating an `Listing ionic application` where i am displaying feeds from an API in the home page. It also has some filter options which is an `actionsheet` with options such as `near by`, `populer` and so on. What i want to do is when user click one of the filter for example populer, i want to do display the new feeds on the same page. How can i do so ??

My code base is as below

home.ts

```
constructor(....){
      this.getFeeds();
  }

//make api call to get the feeds
  getFeeds(){
      const data = localStorage.getItem('userToken');
      this.userPostData.api_token= data;
      this.authService.postData(this.userPostData,'feeds').then((result)=>{
          this.responseData = result;
      })
  }

//Feeds by location

//Actionsheet 
  filters() {
   let actionSheet = this.actionSheetCtrl.create({
     title: 'Sort Events by',
     buttons: [
       {
         text: 'Location',
         icon:'pin',
         handler: () => {
            //Make api call to feeds based on location
         }
       },
       {
         text: 'Popularity',
         icon:'people',
         handler: () => {
            //Make api call to feeds based on location
         }
       }
     ]
   });

   actionSheet.present();
 }
```

And my home.html is

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let item of responseData?.feed"  tappable (click)="viewDetail(item.id)">
    <div class="event-image-holder search-list">
      <img src="http://localhost:8000/{{item.photo_url}}"/>
      <div class="event-attendee-count">
         <ion-icon name="people"></ion-icon> {{item.attendees.length}} are going
      </div>
    </div>
    <ion-card-content>
      <div class="event-info">
        <div class="event-time">
            <!-- 04 Feb -->
        {{item.gmt_date_set | date:'dd MMM'}}
        </div>
        <div class="event-descp">
          <h2>{{item.title}}</h2>
          <p>
            {{item.club.name}}
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
```

Answer (score 0):

After some research here and there tutorials from youtube and udemy, i found that when ever you change the data of the variable it automatically change on the view page.

So in my case if i override the data of `this.responseData` it will automatically updated on the view page with out much doing.